# LWJGL 2 reports wrong display size on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, mouse, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL 2.9.3 to create a window and retrieve mouse coordinates via LWJGLs `Mouse.getX()`,`getY()` methods. The results by those methods and by events via `getEventX()` are equal.

The coordinates I get back are correct using linux (ubuntu gnome, dm: i3) but aren't when using windows 8. (I considered wrong monitor settings due to second monitor but couldn't achieve anything by disconnecting/resetting/changing them)

Here are 2 images with estimations of the coordinates I get on both operating systems.

Correct, linux:

[image]

Incorrect, windows:

[image]

When activating fullscreen, I get data for both variables, the X coordinate seems to fit, the Y coordinate is somewhat off and changes for multiple clicks on the same location.

Here is the entire code I'm using for this example:
https://gist.github.com/Geosearchef/5889a13edd6b983959e837a8506170af

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this? A bug with LWJGL? I was already using that exact version on Windows and was able to do it. A problem with my installation?

UPDATE: `((WindowsDisplay) Mouse.implementation).mouse.last_x` has the correct value, `((WindowsDisplay) Mouse.implementation).mouse.last_y` is correct if you set its origin at 1/3rd from the top. Below that it get's negative --> getting clamped. I don't know though why x gets set to -1.

UPDATE: The mouse implementation fails due to the Display class returning 0, 100 as width and height. This is ignored in the case of fullscreen. Width and height are set correctly in the beginning but are later overriden by an update (resize) call from the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I've now figured out the problem. I used the natives of and old LWJGL implementation (2.9.1) which were stored in my project files.